POSIX standards and semantics of semaphores
I'm trying to understand the semantics of semaphores.
Here is some code:
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

sem_t sem;

void *helper(void *arg) {
        sem_wait(&sem);
        printf("helper woke up\n");
        return NULL;
}

int main() {
        sem_init(&sem, 0, 0);
        pthread_t tid;
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, helper, NULL);
        sleep(1);
        sem_post(&sem);
        sem_wait(&sem);
        printf("main woke up\n");
        exit(0);
}                   

Here main creates a helper thread, sleeps for a second to be (almost) sure that the helper has run and waited on the semaphore, and then tries to post and wait on the semaphore in quick succession. According to POSIX (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sem_post.html):

If the value of the semaphore resulting from this operation is zero, then one of the threads blocked waiting for the semaphore shall be allowed to return successfully from its call to sem_wait().

So, I would expect "helper woke up" to be printed. However, if you actually run this code on Linux, "main woke up" is typically observed, meaning that by default semaphores on Linux are allowed to be not fair.
My question is: why is this behavior allowed? Yes, you can say "it's easier to implement" but that does not explain why semaphores have been designed with these particular semantics.
Elsewhere, (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) it says that this behavior is preferable in some situations. In what situation would a non-fair semaphore be preferable? I'd appreciate any detailed source on this topic.
Edit: please don't make the sleep(1) the focus of the post. Assume that the helper thread waits on the semaphore (like it almost always does) in any way that you like (yield, barrier, no timer ticks, whatever). I'm interested in the semaphore semantics here.

"... sleeps for a second to be (almost) sure that the helper has run" - Are you sure that the helper is actually run within that second? You could e.g. add printf() statement to the helper function before the sem_wait, and check whether its message is actually printed in your scenario.

Re. "when a thread sem_posts and there is another thread waiting on that semaphore, one of the waiters shall be woken up and allowed to return from sem_wait": where did you read that?  I don't see it anywhere in the POSIX link provided.

@Tsyvarev While anything is technically possible, the computer would have to be so overloaded as to be unusable for the other thread not to run during that second.

@G.M. If the value of the semaphore resulting from this operation is zero, then one of the threads blocked waiting for the semaphore shall be allowed to return successfully from its call to sem_wait().

From the link: " If the Process Scheduling option is supported, the thread to be unblocked shall be chosen in a manner appropriate to the scheduling policies and parameters in effect for the blocked threads. In the case of the schedulers SCHED_FIFO and SCHED_RR, the highest priority waiting thread shall be unblocked, and if there is more than one highest priority thread blocked waiting for the semaphore, then the highest priority thread that has been waiting the longest shall be unblocked. If the Process Scheduling option is not defined, the choice of a thread to unblock is unspecified.".

@wohlstad But there aren't multiple processes waiting on the semaphore.

@Barmar the text from the link mentions mainly threads, not processes.

@wohlstad Same difference. At the time sem_post() is called there's only one waiter.

@Barmar OK, it was the OP's use of the term another that had me confused -- I obviously read too much into something that wasn't there :-)

@Barmar I agree. I just gave the quote from the link for additional info. But how do you explain the behavior observed by the OP ?

@Oka: Adding return NULL; changes nothing in my tests.  I added it to the code in the question.  Hope this makes your reasoning easier :-)

It would also be a good idea, generally, to check all return values and make sure that all the system calls are actually succeeding.  (Or check with strace if you are lazy).  But in my tests they do all succeed.

@Barmar At the time sem_post() is called there's only one waiter  But now you need to define "at the time" precisely.

@AndrewHenle Read my answer, and pay careful attention to the last paragraph about the "as if" rule, which allows optimizations like this.

@Barmar The "as-if" rule is totally unnecessary here - child thread starts, goes into sem_wait() and goes to sleep, waiting on the semaphore.  Parent thread does it's 1-second sleep(), wakes up, and then BAM-BAM calls sem_post() and sem_wait() in rapid succession while the child thread is still in deep sleep, blocked on the semaphore.  By the time the kernel can examine the state of the semaphore, there are two threads blocked in it.  The child thread in deep sleep, the parent thread hot and running.  Guess which one acquires the semaphore?  The expectation here is just wrong.

@AndrewHenle Everyone is understanding the spec as describing something synchronous: Inside sem_post() it checks if there are any threads blocked in sem_wait() and immediately unblocks them, and doesn't return until it has done that. So there shouldn't be any BAM-BAM. My point is that you can't distinguish the two cases, because it's not possible to know whether the first thread is blocked.

@Barmar (cont)  That expectation seems to be based on a belief that there is such as thing as "X in thread A happens before Y in thread B" in the absence of any explicit calls to thread synchronization objects.  Such a relationship simply does not exist.

@AndrewHenle; The concern I have with that theory is that the spec appears to imply that checking the state of the semaphore, and unblocking a blocked process if any, is done before sem_post returns.

@NateEldredge "Allowed to return" doesn't mean "immediately returns".

@AndrewHenle: sem_post is defined as a synchronization operation, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html.

@NateEldredge It synchronizes memory - "The following functions synchronize memory with respect to other threads"  There's no order-of-execution requirement, only "one of the threads blocked waiting for the semaphore shall be allowed to return successfully from its call to sem_wait(). ...the choice of a thread to unblock is unspecified."

@AndrewHenle: But during the execution of sem_post, the main thread is definitely not blocked in sem_wait, so it isn't among the threads that can be chosen.  So to explain the behavior consistently with the standard, either we have to allow that the operations described for sem_post don't happen synchronously with its execution (which is implicitly the case for all other system calls), but asynchronously at a later time; or, as Barmar suggests, that during the execution of sem_post there are no threads blocked waiting for the semaphore.

@AndrewHenle: I mean, when you read the description of, let's say, mkdir(2), it's understood that the operations it describes are performed synchronously with the call, and are visible systemwide before the call returns.  It's creating the directory now, not sometime next week.  You seem to be suggesting that sem_post is somehow not subject to that same principle.

It does seem a bit odd that the helper thread may have successfully executed a "block me" syscall, may appear in some internal queue of the semaphore struct, but not count as "a thread waiting on the semaphore" in order to be consistent with the standard. This is even the case if there are 100 such helper threads!

@NateEldredge Define "synchronously" between threads when the signal that thread A called sem_post() doesn't have enough time even at close to the speed of light to make it to thread B before thread A gets blocked in sem_wait().

@JoshLevi You're attempting to force your macro-world view of time onto systems measured in nanometers and timed in nanoseconds where the term "same time" has absolutely zero meaning.

@NateEldredge The main thread, running in kernel mode, would simply need to decrement the semaphore and mark the helper thread runnable...  You're completely discounting that by the time the kernel gets around to seeing which thread to wake up, the main thread is already blocked in sem_wait() and is still "hot" and eminently runnable.  Thus the choice is between a "hot" recently-running thread that's ready to go and a "cold" thread (or threads) in deep sleep even if they're marked runnable is an easy one to make.  "the choice of a thread to unblock is unspecified."

Heck, if the semaphore has an adaptive locking scheme where a thread spins for a bit waiting for the lock before sleeping, the parent thread might actually still be spinning and the choice is even easier.

As far as the supposed "requirement" to wake up a waiting thread before sem_post() returns?  How?!?  Mark each thread that's found to be waiting with an "You can wake me!" tag so that threads that happen to call sem_wait() "after" the call to sem_post() "happened" don't get woken?  Well, then, how do you do that if two threads call sem_post() "simultaneously"?  Again - "at the same time" has zero meaning - threads run faster than states can be propagated.

Linux is not POSIX-compliant, thus the POSIX semaphore semantic may be not implemented in respect to the norm.

One way that this can be preferable is that it reduces context switches. The thread that calls sem_post() is allowed to continue running without having to resume the thread blocked in sem_wait().
By the time the scheduler makes the decision of which thread to unblock, the main thread has called sem_wait(). Then it chooses which of the waiters to unblock. Then it can base this on scheduling priorities, as described in the rest of the paragraph that the quote was taken from, or choose arbitrarily. And it may choose the main thread to avoid a context switch.
Even though it's unlikely that it would take more than a second for the second thread to run, there are no requirements for it to run right away (unless scheduler priorities have been configured). So decisions like this can act as if there were an arbitrary delay in running the second thread. Optimizations like there's no observable difference in behavior due to timing windows like this.
An important thing to remember is that specifications like POSIX describe behavior in abstract terms, it's not trying to force a specific implementation.

This is indeed a possible explanation. +1. Although I must admit that in this scenario [at least by default] I would expect the helper to be woken (and the semaphore to be more "fair"). However the behavior reported by the OP is reproducable at least in Godbolt - as much as it is relevant. I even added a printf to make sure the helper started, and return from the helper function (to avoid UB).

It could be preferable, but by the letter of the spec it seems to be illegal?

Since there are no requirements for scheduling timing, the code can run as if it took more than a second to start the other thread.

But normally when POSIX specifies the effects of a system call, it's implied that those effects are complete and visible before the system call returns, not that they are simply planned to happen at some arbitrary later date.  So I would read this as saying that the unblocking of the waiter must be complete before sem_post returns, and the semaphore decrements atomically with the unblock.  Thus the value of the semaphore should be zero when the main thread calls sem_wait, and it should get stuck there.  I agree there can be an arbitrary delay before the helper makes further progress.

The "as if" rule allows it to act as if the first thread hasn't yet called "sem_wait()". In that case it just increments the semaphore and returns immediately.

@NateEldredge but if this is the case (that the effects should be visible) why the helper is not the woken thread ? In my test it surely started and called sem_wait, and so when sem_post is executed it should be the only one waiting and therefore woken up. Isn't it ?

@wohlstad: Yes, that's why I also thought that the observed behavior was not legal.  But Barmar has a point that we can't prove that the helper thread is actually blocked in sem_wait when sem_post is called; everything we observe is also consistent with the possibility that the helper has stalled just before calling sem_wait.  (On the other hand, strace shows that the helper is in fact blocked in sem_wait - but I guess that's not really "observable behavior".)

@NateEldredge I see, could be.

It's an optimization that reduces scheduling overhead. Many optimizations are based on the "as if" rule.

Even putting a printf() in the helper() function doesn't prevent it. The thread could pause between printf() and sem_wait().

Please let's not focus on the scheduling behavior. Assume the helper always calls sem_wait (as it almost always does). Why then is the observed behavior not in violation of POSIX spec?

@JoshLevi Because the "as if" rule means it doesn't matter unless you can prove it.

@barmar What exactly do you mean by "when the scheduler makes the decision of which thread to unblock?" Most of the time, this code produces exactly zero non voluntary context switches, so the scheduler isn't involved at all. Semaphores may use syscalls to block threads but are implemented in userspace.

@JoshLevi I assumed sempahores were implemented in the kernel.

@Barmar well you are wrong and have not engaged with the substance of my question

I thought "In what situation would a non-fair semaphore be preferable?" was the substance of the question. MInimizing context switches is the situation.

can you provide a source that this was indeed the rationale?

is this behavior consistent with the POSIX spec?

No, I can't prove this is the actual rationale. It's a possible justification.

I think I've answered the "is it allowed" question multiple times.

ok I see the point. but could you not read whether the state of the thread is blocked from something like /proc/? or does that not count as "observable behavior"?

@JoshLevi I don't think looking at /proc or using strace counts. Specifications are written in terms of abstract behaviors, these look at low-level implementation details.

@JoshLevi Your expectation to be able to depend on which thread a sem_post() wakes up from a sem_wait() is unrealistic.  In the absence of explicit synchronization in your code, there simply is no "X happens in thread A before Y happens in thread B" relationship.  Period.  And in this particular case, there is no way for your child thread to synchronize the fact that it's blocked in a semaphore to other threads - because it's blocked in a semaphore.  A synchronization call of any type that says, "I'll soon be blocked in a semaphore!" doesn't work.

As far as reading /proc, that's a TOCTOU bug waiting to happen - that tells you the thread was blocked in a semaphore.

@AndrewHenle TOCTOU generally refers to something that causes a state change unexpectedly between the to T's. But if you expect a state change and it doesn't happen, that's not a TOCTOU bug.

hmm. so does all this mean that the "set of threads waiting on a semaphore" isn't an observable / well defined concept? in that case, what would it even mean for a semaphore to be "fair", if we can assume that all threads are at the point "just before" the sem_wait?

Is fairness guaranteed somewhere? Where did you get the idea that it's supposed to be fair?

Agree, nowhere is it guaranteed. But for instance, the Java semaphore doc says that semaphores can be either "fair" or not. However, according to "as if" semantics, is there an observable difference between the two?

You can probably observe it statistically, but not for a specific call.

Just like you can't tell if a coin or die is fair by throwing it just once, you need many throws.

so like if they were fair, we would have seen "helper woke up" more often?
anyways I think you've helped me understand things better. thank you!

Yes, if it's fair. But if it has an optimization like I suggest, it's biased in favor of the current thread.
